# Maven project stuck on "Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]"

Tags: tomcat

I created a Maven project and integrated `tomcat7-maven-plugin` in POM file. When I run the project, it freezes on `Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]`.

Here is the trace provided by jstack:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin>jstack 7144
2016-04-07 21:04:39
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.74-b02 mixed mode):

"http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0  tid=0x0000000018dd1000
nid=0x1a78 waiting on condition [0x00000000225de000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0  tid=0x0000000019bb2800 ni
d=0xa60 runnable [0x00000000224de000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketIm
pl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:
409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x00000000e0ecf398> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(De
faultServerSocketFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:
216)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000019913000 nid=0x194c waiting on condition [0x00000000223df000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-2" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000019c4a000 nid=0x1acc runnable [0x000000001e13f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.getQueuedCompletionStatus(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$300(Iocp.java:46)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:333)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000018af7000 nid=0x1480 runnable [0x00000000191ef000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    - locked <0x0000000081b68a30> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000018a73000  nid=0x1b90 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000016eb2800 nid=0x18c0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000016eb0000 nid=0x175c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000016ead000 nid=0xb00
waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000016eab000 nid=0x13e0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000016eaa000 nid=0x1a34
runnable [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0000000016e9a800 nid=0x196c in Object.wait() [0x000000001820f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000081b69148> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000081b69148> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000016e79000 nid=0xc1c
in Object.wait() [0x000000001810f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000081b691a0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x0000000081b691a0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000215d800 nid=0x1b08 in   Object.wait() [0x000000000225d000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000da813360> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.waitIndefinitely(Abst ractRunMojo.java:1357)
    - locked <0x00000000da813360> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMo jo.java:595)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000016e77800 nid=0x6dc runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002276800 nid=0x6b8 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002278000 nid=0x1b34 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000227a000 nid=0x18d4 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000227b800 nid=0x668 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000018a7f000 nid=0xf24 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 338
```

Could you help me please ?